# Как реализовать анимацию css через JS

Tags: javascript, css

Необходимо, что бы при клике на ссылку вырисовывалась линия, попытался менять ширину линии с помощью JS, предварительно установив элементу transition,но не помогло,  она просто моментально появляется, при том, что если поменять ширину вручную, то анимация срабатывает.

JS

```
 function a1(){

    line1 = document.getElementById("line1");
    line2 = document.getElementById("line2");
    line3 = document.getElementById("line3");
    line4 = document.getElementById("line4");
    line5 = document.getElementById("line5");

    line1.style.display = "block";
    line1.style.width = "2.5%";
    line2.style.display = "none";
    line2.style.width = "0";
    line3.style.display = "none";
    line3.style.width = "0";
    line4.style.display = "none";
    line4.style.width = "0";
    line5.style.display = "none";
    line5.style.width = "0";
}
```

css

```
#line1,
#line2,
#line3,
#line4,
#line5{
    content:"";
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    top:74px;
    left:73%;
    display: none;
    transition: 1s;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let line = document.getElementById('line');

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  line.classList.add("lineFull");
});
```

```css
.line{
    background: black;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    transition: all .4s;
  }
  
  .lineFull{
    width:300px;
    transition: all .4s;
  }
  
  button{
  margin-top:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="line" class="line"></div>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать, если я правильно понял вот пример!

Answer (score 0):

> не помогло, она просто моментально появляется

Вероятно, это потому что ты меняешь свойство `display`. Попробуй переключать не его, а `visibility` или `opacity`.

И желательно переключать класс активного состояния линии (используя метод [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)), вместо такого насилия над атрибутом `style` каждого элемента.
То есть, добавив всем линиям класс, например `line`, в CSS:
`.line.active { visibility: visible; width: 2.5%; }`
, и скриптом убирать/добавлять этот класс на элементах, например так:

```
function setActiveLine(idx) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.line')].forEach(
    (line, i) => line.classList.toggle('active', i === idx)
  ); 
}
```

---

Еще вариант - использование экспериментального [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API):

```js
const lines = document.querySelectorAll('.line'); 
let i = 0;
animateLine(i); 
setInterval(() => animateLine(i = (++i > 3) ? 0 : i), 1e3); 

function animateLine(idx) {
  console.clear(), console.log('Анимируем "линию" с индексом ' + idx); 
  lines[idx].animate([
    { width: '0', background: '#aaa' }, 
    { width: '50%', background: `hsl(${idx * 100}, 100%, 50%)` }
  ], { duration: 1e3, easing: 'ease-in' }); 
}
```

```css
.line { width: 0; height: 8px; }
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

Для процессора это немного тяжелее чем CSS-анимации и переходы (transitions), но использование данного API может быть удобно в некоторых случаях.